# Delete API call is failing in JMeter but is successful in PostMan

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have a delete API http request in Jmeter which is like "serverName/ApplName/api/deleteDataset/{datasetId}"

And a delete Content api request which is similar to the above request

But strangely both of these apis are failing with the below error:

Response code:400 Response message:Bad Request

Please note when i am trying the same API in postmen it is passing without any error.

I have tried recording it through JMeter test recorder. But when i tried to run the same script with the new dataset Id or Content Id it is failing again

Also i tried linking PostMan and JMeter test script recorder but when i sent the request through Postman it failed immediately with the bad request 400. Now the exact same request from Postman without Jmeter recorder is passing without any issue.Could it be some kind of security block? I mean is the application treating the requests from JMeter insecure for a delete API?[image]

Answer (score 0):

We cannot tell what's wrong without seeing requests which come from Postman and JMeter, I can only suggest using 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the requests originating from Postman and JMeter and comparing them paying attention to everything: URL, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), body data (if any), etc.

Once you amend your JMeter configuration to send the same request as Postman does (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)) the request from JMeter should be successful as well.

In order to troubleshoot recording issue make sure to import JMeter's certificate into Postman

[image]

and if the issue is still there check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.